# How to properly cast types with autocompletion from IDE in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am implementing a utility for strictly typed backend requests using TypeScript and Fetch API. This utility has a separate file with possible API methods to use. The endpoint's type information is written as an interface that stores the following information:

- Array of path parameters
- Query parameters object
- Endpoint string

This is how I implement this:

```js
interface ApiRecord {
  endpoint: string;

  /** Path parameters */
  params: string[];

  /** Query parameters */
  query: Record<string, string>;
}
```

Then when the function is called, this `ApiRecord` is used to create query settings based on it and the result is the following type:

```js
interface ApiRequest<T extends ApiRecord> {
  method: HTTPMethodType,
  params: Record<T['params'][number], string>
  query: T['query']
}
```

But there are some problems. For example, strings from the `params` array are not autocompleting by IDE when writing a `params` object in `ApiRequest`; same situation for `query`.

How can I implement these two interfaces so that the IDE substitutes values from `ApiRecord` and it is possible to type query parameters (i.e. key: type)?

Comment: I was able to solve the first problem with `ApiRequest['params']` autocompletion: `type AsKeys<T extends readonly string[]> = {[K in T[number]]: string}`. This works provided that the variable passed to `T` will contain an array of strings with `as const`. I would like to get rid of `as const` if possible.

Comment: Show us a [mre]. Right now we have no idea what you're talking about. Yes, we have your interfaces. No, we don't know how to *reproduce* the problem and figure it out from there. If we can't reproduce your problem, we can only take turns stabbing in the dark. Hope you understand, thanks!

Comment: @kelsny sorry about that. Honestly, I will learn how to ask questions correctly on StackOverflow :). Now I will update the text of the question, thanks for the correction 